# What are the differences between the difficulty levels in Tomb Raider?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I would like to know:

- Do the quantity of enemies increase in the harder difficulties?
- Does the salvage or XP received change?
- Are there any enemy AI behavior changes? Do they become "smarter"?
- Are stealth attempts harder? Are you more easily detected?
- Any other difficulty changes?

Answer (score 6):

I've completed the game on hard and played around with other difficulties.

The only differences appear to be:

- Quick time events are, er, quicker. You have less time to hit that one button.
- Damage done to you by enemies is higher - on hard a single rifle burst can kill you.
- Non head-shot damage appears to be lower.

On my hard playthough I fully upgraded all the guns and skills just before the *point of no return* (the game warns you when you reach it), but that was with all treasures found and all challenges complete.

On Xbox there don't appear to be any achievements related to difficulty.

Comment: Are all QTEs including environmental ones affected, or just combat QTEs such as finishing attacks, counterattacks, and minibosses? It does say "Combat Difficulty" after all.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro Just combat I think - hard to be certain, but the environmental ones were much easier, while some of the combat ones were eye-blinks.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing on normal and got to a battle that I just couldn't beat (I died probably 100 times in this one part!), so scaled down to easy for that scene. The main difference I noticed was that it aims a bit for you. It's very subtle, but when I pull out my bow and press on the trigger to find the "red" target, it's much more likely to already be lined up for me while on easy mode. The bad guys can still move out of the way, but I don't have to waste time lining it up in the first place (something I'm not terribly good at).

In the non-combat zones, I haven't noticed any difference at all. I don't think the playthrough is different on different levels - just the way the guns / controls handle seems to be different.